# Only Allow Intent Action from specific app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-security

I'm working on a project about sharing files from one app to another app on a same device.

Here is the problem, I have two apps A and B installed on a device. app B stores files and app A wants to get these file.

For now, app A will fire a PICK ACTION intent to request files from app B. Because this intent is implicit intent, android system will bring up all apps can handle ACTION_PICK intent.

This will bring up a security leak that any app which fire PICK ACTION will have the potential to access files in App B. the data in App B could only be accessed by app A.

Is there a way that make app B's data only exposed to app A?

Thanks

Comment: You have to give a better explication to your question

Comment: I have modified the describtion. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If these apps are in different cellphones you have to implement a web server to do that

Comment: No, they are on a same device. I have add this to the description.

Comment: Explain why you want to share the file through intent? You can place it in phone(internal or external) storage and then select the file from other application.